# how to activate LDAPLoginModule in Apache Karaf 3.0.3

Tags: authentication, ldap, osgi, jaas, karaf

I want to active Ldap Login Module in apache karaf 3.0.3.

My karaf-jaas-module.xml is ;

```
      .
      .        
      .   

    <jaas:config name="karaf" rank="2">
      <jaas:module className="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule" flags="required">
        initialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
        connection.username=admin
        connection.password=xxxxxxx
        connection.protocol=
        connection.url=ldap://activedirectory_host:389
        user.base.dn=cn=orcladmin,cn=users,dc=vmldapdevelop,dc=com
        user.filter=(sAMAccountName=%u)
        user.search.subtree=true
        role.base.dn=ou=Groups,ou=there,DC=local
        role.name.attribute=cn
        role.filter=(member=%nsdn)
        role.search.subtree=true
        authentication=simple
      </jaas:module>
    </jaas:config>

   .
   .
   .
```

And i wrote jaas:realm-list in karaf console and not seen LdapLoginModule.

```
karaf@root()> jaas:realm-list
Index | Realm Name | Login Module Class Name

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.properties.PropertiesLoginModule
2     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.publickey.PublickeyLoginModule
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its in blueprint folder. And this folder is in jaas_module bundle. But change anything in this xml, karaf doesn't seen it. Because its override it.

I solve my problem. I create new xml file, which name is **ldap-module.xml** and my configuration is in it. And i put this xml in **deploy** folder.

So, my new xml override other xml and when i write "jaas:realm-list" on karaf console, i saw this output ;

```
        __ __                  ____
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/

  Apache Karaf (3.0.3)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

karaf@root()>
karaf@root()>
karaf@root()>
karaf@root()> jaas:realm-list
Index | Realm Name | Login Module Class Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule
karaf@root()>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run any commands after placing this file in deploy folder? I have placed the file in deply folder but it doesn ot auto-deploy

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the xml is maybe in the wrong place in the bundle. it should be in OSGI-INF/blueprint like other blueprint contexts. You also need to have the correct namespace defs in the header of the blueprint xml.

You can check if your blueprint xml is processed by doing bundle:services . You should see a BlueprintContainer service. If not then the blueprint is either not picked up at all or the extender finds an error. You can use the diag command to show blueprint errors.